# Archive template not working for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am registering a custom post type called "Products & Services". I have created a file within `wp-content/themes/theme/` called `archive-products&services.php` but it's not using this file.

I also tried `archive-products & services.php`, `archive-productsandservices.php` but still it wont load the template.

```
register_post_type( 'Products & Services',
    array(
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products and Services' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Service' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'productsandservices')

    )
);
```

It works fine on two other custom post types called 'news' and 'products'. Is this an issue with blank spaces in the post type?

Comment: The post type name should be all lowercase with underscores. Use the labels for the human-readable name for the post type. This will be how it’s done in any example that you can find.

Comment: Thanks. The examples I found were single worded.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was the & which WordPress cannot support as is. That is because & is used as part of a URL to join query vars together. Like this:

```
example.com/file.php?foo=bar&baz=zoo
```

Also, as pointed out in comments file names have to follow the naming standard. Which is clearly laid out in the documentation.

The format is `archive-[slug].php`

That's why when you renamed the file it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress doesn't support special characters in post types.

However, it would be useful to point out the codex doesn't state this. All it says is **(max 20 characters, cannot container capital letters, underscores or spaces)**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score -1):

After changing the post type to "Products and Services" it works with the file name "archive-productsandservices.php". I guess Wordpress doesn't support special characters in post types.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This fixed it.